# Getting 2 errors, the project only has a standard windows form

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++

I'm new to programming and I just made a windows form in my new project, I've changed the project properties and I still get these 2 errors:

---

The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.

command-line error: cannot open metadata file "System.Runtime.dll"

---

I don't really know what to do and I'd like some help.

Comment: Do you use visual studio? Have you installed Net sdk? You can download it from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Comment: Yes, I use vs 2019 pro. I've downloaded the Net sdk from your link and it still gives me the error message. I've just tried adding the full .Net support instead of just the CLI support. Now it gives me 2061 warnings, the couple first ones are: No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Choosing "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are creating a C++ winform project. After modifying project properties, do you add below codes into your form.cpp:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    //WinformCDemo is your project name
WinformCDemo::MyForm form;
Application::Run(%form);
}
```

And then, you need to re-open visual studio. The workround: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9529502-6304-4aa6-90ee-0757ab258d87/create-c-windows-forms-application-in-visual-studio-2017?forum=winforms